# Test method to find out the nominal voltage of an Electromagnetic Clutch?

Tags: electrical-engineering

Is there any (non-destructive) test method to find out the nominal voltage of an Electromagnetic Clutch?

I have an Electromagnetic Clutch from an very old machine that came for restoration, and there is no identification plate on the clutch or on the machine, I don't have the electrical schematic of this equipment, model or manufacturer... All the electrical part was removed a long time ago and there is no notes on the client side either (!). Looking at other components of the machine, it can be 12, 24 or 48 Vdc.

I can send the clutch to an expert, but I'd like to know if it's possible to find out with some testing.

Comment: Insulation materials can give you an idea of temperature limit.  You'd have to figure out from resistance and thermal characteristics what temperature something would have to be to dissipate energy from each of the voltages.  If it exceeds some insulation you see, it likely means that voltage is too high.  Another approach would be figuring the min voltage needed for it to do its job.

Comment: Measure the resistance of the winding, then work out the amps at each voltage. Then look at the thickness of the copper wire. Now apply common sense.